# Запрет ПК версии сайта на мобильных устройствах

Tags: javascript, html, браузер, кроссбраузерность

Как запретить пользователю переходить на «Версия для ПК» или «Полная версия сайта»? Хотя бы в какую сторону думать подскажите.

Comment: Не надо в эту сторону думать

Answer (score 1):

Используй MediaQuery в css, и в зависимости от размера экрана просто скрывай ссылки

Answer (score 1):

в javascript фильтровать useragent и редиректить в случае если агент является мобильным или десктопным. Либо использовать htaccess